# how to move button action down along y axis iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uitextfield

i have a button acton with outlet btnAdd, when it pressed it add text field, i want to move button action also below textfields and same want to recover back when button BtnRemove pressed,

```
 - (IBAction)btnAddTxtField:(id)sender {

    textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(76, ([txtFieldArray count] * 30), 191, 25)];
    [textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleLine];
    textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
    textField.placeholder = @"Enter text";
    textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    textField.delegate = self;
    [myScrollview addSubview:textField];
    [txtFieldArray addObject:textField];


    CGRect frame = bottomView.frame;
    frame.origin.y += textField.frame.size.height + 5;

    btnAdd = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(210, ([txtFieldArray count] *30), 20, 20)];
   frame.origin.y += btnAdd.frame.size.height +5;
    bottomView.frame = frame;
    textField.hidden = NO;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have modified the `frame` variable, set it to the button in an animation block:

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
     [btnAdd setFrame:frame];
 } 
 completion:^(BOOL finished){
      //Do something on completion if you want
 }];
```

Obviously you can change the animation duration (0.2) to anything that you would like.  To reverse it, do the same, set the origin.y of the `frame` CGRect, and set it to the button in the animation block above.

Comment: Would help to know what the error is? fixed a small typo just now if that was it. There was an extra ^ after the `(BOOL finished)`

Comment: @QualityCoder did this end up working for you? Pls accept answer if it did. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: delay: options: animations: completion:];
```

Would be your choice. You can check the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) .